# Dropdown list split colors

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a dropdown list that shows when I search a user in Active Directory. I used JQuery UI autocomplete to do it but after 4 users in the list, the background color changes.
So here is my form, with input autocomplete:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="~/Home/SearchUserResult">
                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInput"> 
                    Nom et/ou Prénom 
                </label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="searchName" id="searchName" placeholder="Nom et/ou prénom" />
            <img src="~/Content/Images/hourglass.gif" style="display:none" id="loadingImg"/>
             <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="searchValidate"> Rechercher </button><br />
            </form>
</div>
```

Now my jquery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var distName = [];
        var dispName = [];
        $("#searchName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $("#loadingImg").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SearchUserWhileTyping",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { name: $("#searchName").val() },
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            distName[item.displayName] = item.distinguishedName;
                            //distName.push(item.distinguishedName);
                            dispName.push(item.displayName);
                            return {
                                label: item.displayName
                            }
                        }));
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#loadingImg").hide();
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                var res;
                var index = 0;
                alert(ui.item.label);
                $.each(dispName, function (key, value) {
                    if (ui.item.label == value)
                        res = distName[value];
                });

                //alert(disName.distinguishedName);
                var link = '@Url.Action("ShowUserInfo", "Home", new { distinguishedName = "value"})';
                link = link.replace("value", res);
                window.location.href = link;
                //window.location.href = Url.ActionLink("Test", "ShowUserInfo", "Home", new {distinguishedName = ui.item.distinguishedName});
            },
            minLength: 4
        })
    });

</script>
```

In this script I retrieve values from Active Directory while you are typing, I also show an image while loading, and added arrays so I can redirect immediately on clicking a user. Also, here is a picture of what my form looks like. Thanks for your help!

[image]

**EDIT** I noticed that css does not change the background color of the four first names in the list. If I add some css like `background-color:lightgrey` here's what happens:[image]

As you can see the upper part doesn't change but the lower has been changed. This is close but still visible so not great.

Comment: can you create a Fiddle replicating your issue? Its a local api you are using

Comment: How can I populate my dropdown list on jsfiddle? I gonna try. No you are right it's not a local api, I had forgotten. I had some issues with local api, didn't know why. I actually posted on SO about this problem but got downvoted :( guess I wasn't clear.

Comment: Ok I changed to local api and it works, thanks buddy :)